# Sollin's Minimum Spanning Tree Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

Yes this is homework. I was wondering if someone could explain the process of Sollin's (or Borůvka's) algorithm for determining a minimum spanning tree. Also if you could explain how to determine the number of iterations in the worst case, that would be great.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bor%C5%AFvka's_algorithm ? If there's something specific you don't understand, ask about it. Otherwise, read your textbook, wikipedia, wikipedia's sources, etc.

Comment: Could someone please explain why this Gareth Rees person keeps removing the tag "discrete mathematics" from this question and why it is being down voted? I'm not angry; I just don't really understand the way this site works as I am new. This question seems like a legitimate thing to ask at this sort of website, and I believe it falls under discrete mathematics especially because of the fact that this homework comes from a course titled "Discrete Mathematics".

Comment: Discrete mathematics is a collection of topics to do with integers (as opposed to continuous mathematics). So, sequences, recurrences, summation, generating functions, binomials, finite calculus etc. Algorithms provide lots of *examples* for discrete maths, but that doesn't mean that all questions about algorithms are questions about discrete maths. As for the downvotes, I dunno. (I think your question's fine, just mis-tagged.)

Comment: Unfortunately, sir, algortithms themselves don't imply discrete mathematics, but this example of an algorithm utilizes discrete math. So, as you haven't provided an answer, I would have to say this question still stands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a top level, the algorithm works as follows:

- Maintain that you have a number of spanning trees for some subgraphs. Initially, every vertex of the graph is a m.s.t. with no edges.
- In each iteration, for each of your spanning trees, find a cheapest edge connecting it to another spanning tree. (This is a simplification.)

The worst case in terms of iterations is that you always merge pairs of trees. In that case, the number of trees you have will halve in each iteration, so the number of iterations is logarithmic in the number of nodes.

Also note that there is a special trick involved in choosing the edges to add: if you were not careful, you might introduce a circle when tree A connects to tree B, tree B connects to tree C and tree C connects to tree A. (This can only happen if all three edges chosen have the same weight. The trick is to have an arbitrary but fixed tie-breaker, like a fixed order of the edges.)

So there, that's my back-of-index-card overview.

Comment: So in the case of an 100 node tree, the worst case would take log2 (100) or 7 iterations?

Comment: @Brendan: yeah, sounds right. I admit I don't care about constant factors the O()-Notation hides from you, but I don't think there's any here.

Comment: Thanks. I think between your explanation and my research, I'm using this algorithm correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the layman's terminology.

- First select a vertex
- Check all the edges from that vertex and select one with the minimum
  weight
- Do this for all the vertices ( some edges may be selected more than
  once)
- You will get connected components.
- From these connected components select one edge with minimum weight.

Your spanning tree with minimum weight will be formed